# Декремент постфиксный как правильно его использовать

Tags: c#

Объясните пожалуйста почему данный код, при использование постфиксного  декремента

```
int a = 5;//Тут 4
int b = a-- - (a + 2);//Выполняем сначала в скобках так как приоритет
//в скобках 7 и потом отнимает 4 + 7 = (-3)
//Где я припустил 

Console.WriteLine($"Var a: {a}\nVar b: {b}");
string key = Console.ReadLine();
```

Выдает в переменной b результат -1

Когда при такой записи

```
int a = 5;//Тут после операции 6
int b = a++ + (a + 2);
//Здесь 6 + (5+2) = 13

Console.WriteLine($"Var a: {a}\nVar b: {b}");
string key = Console.ReadLine();
```

Результат a=6 b=13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Операнды вычисляются в том порядке, в каком они идут в выражении:

```
int a = 5;
int b = a-- - (a + 2);
```

1. `a -> 5` - первый член в выражении
2. `a-- -> a` становится `4`
3. `(a+2) -> 6` - второй член в выражении
4. `5 - 6 -> -1` - результат

```
int a = 5;
int b = a++ + (a + 2);
```

1. `a -> 5` - первый член в выражении
2. `a++ -> a` становится `6`
3. `(a+2) -> 8` - второй член в выражении
4. `5 + 8 -> 13` - результат

Comment: А скобки добавляют приоритет перед декрементом ?

Comment: @Andrew скобки, в данном случае, определяют из каких операндов (членов) состоит выражение.

Comment: как сложно понять когда все говорят по разному уроки смотрел там по другому все рассказывали. Подскажите видео уроки где доходчиво разъясняют только не англ

Comment: @Andrew не знаю :(

Comment: @Andrew: А вы не учите по видеоурокам. Читайте лучше книги, они рулез.

Comment: @VladD Я бы с радостью, но я плохо понимаю книги, я визуалист быстрее и проще понимаю когда видео. Такая особенность

Comment: @Andrew: Давайте я вам как визуалисту объясню аналогией. Вы пытаетесь извлечь информацию о жителях дома из надписей на заборе. Представили? Это неправильный путь. Почитайте лучше их биографии или отчёт из милиции (это аналог чтения книг). Или поживите с ними вместе (это аналог самостоятельного программирования).

Comment: @VladD хорошая аналогия, спасибо попробую))